# How do I search through the description history for an issue in JIRA?

Tags: jira

So we have a lot of requirements, and at one point an external reference was not supposed to be supported - ie, the requirement changed. This affected several requirements. The description was then changed by deleting the keyword on all affected issues.

Now the external reference is of course back to be supported, and I want to find all my stories (or any issuetypes) that used to have a certain key word in them. ie I want to search through the description history of some issues.

I have no database access, and the only thing I do know is that I made the changes during a two week period. I can of course select all the issues that had a status change in that period, but this will not help me since the status was not changed on all issues.

Since the history is clearly there with my old data and key word, I expected I could perform a search on this content. It appears I cannot... we have scriptrunner installed, but I believe that is it.

Any pointers would be very helpful.

Answer (score 2):

You can use either JIRA's REST API to search for issues and to get their changelog or you can use the JIRA java API in Script Runner groovy scripts.

For the REST API, these are useful resources:

- [GET /rest/api/2/search](https://docs.atlassian.com/jira/REST/latest/#api/2/search-search)
- [GET /rest/api/2/issue/{issueIdOrKey}](https://docs.atlassian.com/jira/REST/latest/#api/2/issue-getIssue)

To get the changelog of the issue(s), you have to add the query parameter *expand* with value *changelog*, e.g. *?expand=changelog,names*

For the JAVA API, take a look at:

- [SearchService](https://docs.atlassian.com/jira/latest/com/atlassian/jira/bc/issue/search/SearchService.html)
- [ChangeHistoryManager.getAllChangeItems](https://docs.atlassian.com/jira/4.4/com/atlassian/jira/issue/changehistory/ChangeHistoryManager.html#getAllChangeItems(com.atlassian.jira.issue.Issue))

In either case you'll have to write some code and run through all the histories to find changes to the description, but it's doable.

Comment: Thanks for the input! This looks to be a more cumbersome way than I hoped for - but given that JQL doesn't support this out of the box I guess I should have expected that...:)

I'll at least take this into account the next time I encounter this issue, what I did now was a date search and just manually verify the history of the 30 odd matches that was changed within that period.